# Using bash eval on a complex single-quoted string

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I have programmatically constructed a string that I want to pass to eval in bash.  This is the string:

```
finalcommand='for user in $(aws iam list-users --output text  --profile myprofile --region us-west-2  | awk '\'' {  print $NF } '\''  );  do aws iam list-access-keys --user $user --output json  --profile profile --region us-west-2  ; done | jq -r . | aha --black | tee /home/mycompany/outputhtml-myprofile2343.html'
```

I pass it through a piece of code to eval it:

```
result=$( eval $finalcommand )
```

But this is what I get back:

```
/scriptcommandbuilder.sh: line 221: for user in $(aws iam list-users --output text --profile myprofile --region us-west-2 | awk ' { print $NF } ' ); do aws iam list-access-keys --user $user --output json --profile myprofile --region us-west-2 ; done | jq -r . | aha --black | tee /home/mycompany/outputhtml-2342343.html: No such file or directory
```

It appears that eval is taking in the entire variable of `$finalcommand`, and then trying to execute it as a filename, when I want it to simply parse it as a string of commands.  If I copy/paste the output from above, it works as it should.  I have tried a lot of various ways to get eval to accept this string as a set of commands, but it continues to see it as one huge filename/string.  How can I get it to see the string as commands?

I tried pulling off the quotes before passing to eval:

```
  finalcommand="${finalcommand:1}"
  finalcommand="${finalcommand::-1}"
```

But this results in the eval failing with a

`` unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' ``

Comment: You should quote the variable `eval "$finalcommand"`

Comment: Try running the command under `set -xv` to see what the shell actually does.

Comment: How did you actually construct `$finalcommand`? I don't think you should get that error with the value you show in the question.

Comment: It would indeed happen if you had literal quotes around the value. But the quotes you show are processed by the shell where the assignment happens, they're not lierally in the value.

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Comment: I had tried putting double quotes around "$finalcommand".  I get a 'File name too long' error instead.

Comment: What I am doing is taking the basic command, and I pull it into an array, and then quote/escape anything that can cause issues, (like the single quotes in the awk command).  My program then adds additional parameters for the system that it's going to, (substituting in the profile information and the jq processing), and then constructs the finalcommand, which then should be executed.  It's just a weird issue.  This is in bash ver 4.4.20.

Comment: It's very likely that there's a better (more robust, less dangerous) way to do whatever it is  you need to do than constructing a string then calling `eval` on it. If you create and post a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're doing using mandatory POSIX commands (i.e. `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc. rather than `aws`, `jq`, and `aha`) then we can help you as we'd all have those commands readily available to test with.

Comment: Even a simplified example of `My program then adds additional parameters for the system that it's going to` (such as how you do that and sample parameters) would go a long way toward helping answer the question. Your current `finalcommand` is a hardcoded string so making it a function would be much easier than trying to make it parseable for `eval`.

Comment: In doing some more testing, you can take out of the non-POSIX commands, and it will still return the same error.  There is something about how the string is being set up that is causing the error.  You can make a basic for loop, and it will not work.  Copy/pasting directly to the command line does work.

Comment: take a look at my [mquote (Magic Quote)](https://github.com/clarkwang/magic-aliases), no more quoting headaches.

Comment: Not only does it seem to me a bad idea what you are going to do here, you get the quoting wrong: The opening quote in front of the `for` closes after the  word `awk`. This means that `awk` receives a literal single quote (since you are escaping it with a backslash) as first parameter. This does not make sense.